# GIT credentials disappearing from Windows Credential Manager

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, credentials, git-credential-manager

I've been dealing with my GIT credentials being deleted from Windows Credential Manager in ~24h. I'm using the latest version of GIT as of today (12/22 - 2.29.2), but I don't even know if the deletion is being triggered by GIT Credential Manager (Core) itself or something else.

This is what I observed so far:

Whenever I run a GIT command for the first time in the day (let's say a GIT PULL), a PAT (Personal Access Token) is created. It expires in a year. In the example below, I am using ADO (Azure DevOps) as my repo:

[image: PAT created by GIT]

If I launch Windows Credential Manager (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager) I see this:

[image: Windows Credential Manager]

However, in ~24h this stored credential will be gone and I will be prompted to authenticate again, which is pretty annoying. Any clue on what could be causing this?

This is what I have in my SYSTEM gitconfig file - which came automatically with the installation of GIT:

[image: gitconfig]

Any idea about how to avoid the credentials being deleted I will highly appreciate!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jonathan. You could refer to the troubleshooting steps in the answer and check if they could  make some changes. I just upgraded my git version to 2.29.2. So for the time being, it has not had the same problem.I will continue to try to reproduce this issue(After 24 hours).

Comment: Hi Kevin, I will give it a try! Can you try on your end with helper = manager-core (the default of 2.29.2)? I've just tried a git push here and I was prompted to input my Azure credentials again.

Comment: Of course. I keep the system gitconfig file with the same settings. The gitconfig file in the answer is in the current user folder. Based on my test, the GIT credentials still exists  after 24 hours.

Comment: Kevin, can you test with the same setup I have (same gitconfig entries for the "credential" sections - you can find the ones I am using in the issue description)? I keep losing my saved credentials after ~24h and I am wondering if this is something GIT introduced (and hopefully can be adjusted) or something else is going on here. What I know so far is that a reboot is not causing the credentials to disappear, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: I have tested with the same gitconfig settings and the credentials  hasn't been removed after 24 hours. If you manually add the credentials , will it be deleted after 24 hours?

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to do that... I've used SSO to generate the credentials, so I am not sure what it inserted as "password" there. I tried with the PIN of my smart card (we use smart cards here) with no luck. Ideas?

Comment: You could  use the PAT as the password.

Comment: I will try and will let you know!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked my local git credentials(git version: git version 2.29.2.windows.3) and  the credentials haven't disappeared for the time being.

You could try the following steps to check if the credentials can work as expected.

1.You can **manually** create a credential for Azure Devops Git on the local machine.

**Windows Credential Manager -> Add a Generic Credential**

[image]

Internet or network address format: `git:https://dev.azure.com/organizationname`

2.You can find the `.gitconfig` file content in the **C:\Users\TargetUser**.  Then you could check if the credential is store mode.

```
[credential]
    helper = store
```

If not, you could run the following command to create it and check if the credentials  still be deleted after 24 hours.

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

3.I also tested the same steps on git version 2.28.0 and it can work fine too. You could try to install the previous version of git and try if it works.

**Additional information:** On my local machine, even if the PAT has expired, the git credential will not be deleted automatically.

On the other hand, you can also try to use SSH key authentication for a workaround.

You could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) for more detailed information.